# python packages and logging best practices

Tags: python, logging

I am building a Python pip package and I am wondering what the best practices are please with regards to setting-up a logger.

Currently my project tree structure on the filesystem looks roughly like this:

```
  root
   |
   |
   |- my_proj/
   |      |
   |      |- sub_one/
   |      |- sub_two/
   |      |
   |    __init__.py
   |    app.py
   |
   |
 setup.py
```

I am setting up my logger inside `__init__.py` as follows

```
# contents of __init__.py 

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s"
)
```

Then, anytime I want to log something I have a piece of code similar to this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def add_two(x):
   logger.info('Increasing by 2')
   return x + 2
```

Do you see anything wrong with this way? (ignoring what I am describing below, let's say I am not doing a package...)

Since I am building a pip package, when imported as a library, my package (I think) will take over the logging apparatus changing format etc and this is not standard practice and not desirable.
If I understand well, the calling code should instead register/set-up a logger, something similar to:

```
pip install my_proj

import my_proj
my_proj.register_logger()
```

I do not quite understand how this is done please. Is this good practice by the way? Does anyone have any examples. Inside my code, how I should call the logger so it will print messages, if the calling code registers a logger.

Comment: Don't use basicConfig for a package that will be used in other code. That will break any other logger. Use basicConfig only for standalone code